# Made a function with target href parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c, html

i have a website with role authentication so depends of you role the website show you the aplication. the code of that is:

```
                <asp:Repeater ID="ui_rprApp" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsApp">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                                <div class='<%# "ch-item " + Eval("ESTILO_APP") %>'>

                                    <div class="ch-info">
                                        <p>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="ui_hlkApp" runat="server" Target='<%# Eval("ACRONIMO") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("URL") %>'>
                                                <%# Eval("DESCRIPCION") %>
                                            </asp:HyperLink>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>                               
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsApp" runat="server" 
                        SelectMethod="ConsultarAplicacionesUsuario" TypeName="RNOVirtual.Aplicaciones">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="intIdUsuario" 
                                SessionField="ID_USUARIO" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

and i need to get the URL from Hyperlink and put it in a Javascript function, like

```
NewWindow(Url)
    {
        //open the new window with an iframe
        // Aplicaciones_Usuarios.aspx?href= Url
    }
```

So in that way open another window with an iframe inside and in my iframe put the url that i'm getting

```
<iframe id="iframe1" runat="server" src="Url" style="width:100% !important">



    </iframe>
```

and in the codebehind

```
public partial class Aplicaciones_Usuarios : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string Url;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //something
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what your main question/problem is?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when the user clicks the `HyperLink`, you want to call the JavaScript function `NewWindow(url)`?

Change the `NavigateUrl` in your `HyperLink` to this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="ui_hlkApp" runat="server" Target='<%# Eval("ACRONIMO") %>'
    NavigateUrl=<%# "javascript:NewWindow('" + Eval("URL") + "')"%>>
```